# Unusual Title for a workshop

Tags: grammar

I saw this sign above a roller door on an old Garage in Hobart Tasmania. Procrastitorium. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

From *procrastinate* I think it would mean a place where procrastination occurs. This is not a great sign as signs go as procrastination can be done anywhere, if only we get around to it.

Comment: Well, I found it amusing.